# Postgres CASE WHEN IN query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I've attempted the below query in postgres 11

```sql
CASE
           WHEN planning_status::varchar in (('Application Under Consideration'::varchar,'Appeal In Progress'::varchar))  then 'this_label'
           WHEN planning_status::varchar  = 'Approved' and  actual_completion_date is not null then 'that_label'
    ELSE 'reject_label'
    END
```

I can't get the query to run, initially getting error on mismatching operator to record type. I also attempted `IN (VALUES())` method. The below works:

```sql
       CASE
          WHEN planning_status = 'Application Under Consideration'  then 'this_label'
          WHEN planning_status = 'Appeal In Progress'  then 'this_label'
          WHEN planning_status = 'Application Received'  then 'this_label'
          WHEN planning_status  = 'Approved' and  actual_completion_date is not null then 'that_label'
    ELSE 'reject_label'
    END
```

Is it possible to use the `IN` query within a `CASE WHEN` query with strings. The strings are categorical but not stored as such

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the double parentheses:

```
-- this doesn't work:
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 IN ((1, 2)) THEN 'works' ELSE 'weird' END;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = record
LINE 1: SELECT CASE WHEN 1 IN ((1, 2)) THEN 'works' ELSE 'weird' END...
                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

-- this works:
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 IN (1, 2) THEN 'works' ELSE 'weird' END;

 case  
═══════
 works
(1 row)
```

The reason is that in the first statement, the inner parentheses are forming a composite type (`record`) with two elements, and PostgreSQL doesn't know how to compare that to the integer 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the `=` version works, then this *should* work:

```
  (CASE WHEN planning_status IN ('Application Under Consideration', 'Appeal In Progress', 'Application Received')
        THEN 'this_label'
        WHEN planning_status  = 'Approved' and  actual_completion_date is not null 
        THEN 'that_label'
        ELSE 'reject_label'
   END)
```

There should be no need for an explicit type conversion.  If this doesn't work, what is the type of `planning_status`?

Comment: Thankyou,  putting `CASE WHEN` within `()` has resolved it

Comment: @mappingdom . . . That should actually have nothing to do with the solution.  That is just a habit I use to help my reading of expressions and to prevent other types of errors.